# How to change screen resolution on android-things OS on a Raspberry 3B device with out changing config.txt file?

Tags: android, android-things, android-things-console

I want to have a maximun screen resolution bacause the raspberry is to slow when the resolution is HD or Full HD.

For now, i am able to set the screen resolution to 800x600 adding to followig code to the config.txt on the RPIBOOT partition of the android thing build:

```
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_ignore_edid=0xa5000080
config_hdmi_boost=4
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=9
disable_overscan=0
overscan_left=8
overscan_right=8
overscan_top=8
overscan_bottom=8
```

My problem with this method appear when I do an OTA update through android thing console. When the new build is succesfully installed the file config.txt has no longer the code that I add so my resolution is not set.

So, there is any way to change the resolution programatically?
or, there is a way to change this file programatically without having root access?